# Unable to pass parameter to Telerik report

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

I'm trying to pass a string value to a Telerik report in a Winforms project.  The value gets set correctly in the Load event of the report viewer.  But I can't get the parameter value in the NeedDataSource event of the report.  The error "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'" displays.

Report viewer Load Event.

```
Public Class WorkOrderWithPricesReportViewer

Public Property o As OrderInfo

Private Sub ReportViewer1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.Load

    Dim typeReportSource As New Telerik.Reporting.TypeReportSource
    typeReportSource.TypeName = GetType(WorkOrderHeader).AssemblyQualifiedName

    Dim pOrderID As New Telerik.Reporting.Parameter
    pOrderID.Value = o.orderID
    typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(pOrderID)

    ReportViewer1.ReportSource = typeReportSource
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

End Sub
```

End Class

The NeedDataSource event in the report.  The error occurs when trying to put the parameter value in _wohOrderID

```
Partial Public Class WorkOrderHeader
Inherits Telerik.Reporting.Report

Private _wohOrderID As String

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

End Sub

Private Sub WorkOrderHeader_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.NeedDataSource

    Dim wohReport As Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report = DirectCast(sender, Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report)

    _wohOrderID = wohReport.Parameters("pOrderID").Value.ToString
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could it be because in your ReportViewer1_Load you are setting the parameters on a Telerik.Reporting.TypeReportSource object, then in the NeedDataSource your trying to retrieve them from a Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report object?  Is the DirectCast operation there going to the correct type?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I borrowed the code from [link](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/winforms-report-viewer-manual-setup) and [link](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/using-report-events).  Maybe that combination is not correct but I'm not sure how to change one or the other.

Comment: I can get around this issue by using a shared property but do not want to resort to that if possible.  FWIW, I'm using Telerik Reports 13.1.19.618.

Comment: Pretty rough on Telerik reports, been a few years.  Anyway, when creating your param, doesn't look like you're naming it.  Take a look at https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-parameters-adding-parameters

Comment: The parameter is added in the ReportViewer1_Load event (above).  The value gets set successfuly in this event.   I don't think I need to add it again in the NeedDataSource event.

Comment: Yeah, understand you're adding it.  But I can't see where you are naming it pOrderID.  I thinking when you create the paramerter, you need to set the name property.  ie pOrderID.Name = "pOrderId"

Comment: I believe the problem to be in the NeedDataSource event.  A breakpoint in the Load event shows 1 parameter set for the report.  A breakpoint in the NeedDataSource shows zero parameters.  I changed the event to match [Telerik](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/e-telerik-reporting-report-needdatasource)   But a breakpoint here shows that the parameter value is invalid and throws a KeyNotFound exception.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I changed the Load event to match a telerik example. A breakpoint on the last line shows 1 parameter set for the report:  '    Private Sub ReportViewer1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.Load

        Dim aReportBook As ReportBook = New ReportBook()

        Dim typeReportSourceHeader As New TypeReportSource
        typeReportSourceHeader.TypeName = GetType(WorkOrderHeader).AssemblyQualifiedName

        typeReportSourceHeader.Parameters.Add("pOrderID", o.orderID)
        aReportBook.ReportSources.Add(typeReportSourceHeader)
'

Answer (score 0):

The parameter had to be added to the ReportParameters property within the property window for the report.  I added it programmatically but had to add it to the report property window, as well.  Seems redundant but whatever, it works.  The issue has been resolved.  Thanks, Hursey.

[image]

[image]